# Displaying the menus

Tags: asp.net

i just want my horizontal menus to be display in the every page of the website...how to do that?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a master page as RedFilter suggested. If that's not an option, put your menu in a [user control](http://www.15seconds.com/issue/020319.htm) and include it on each page.

Answer (score 4):

One solution is to put them in your [master page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wtxbf3hh.aspx).